# What is the difference between logger.error { "$err" } and logger.error(err) { "$err" }?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

kotlin's logger looks like:

```
open class KLogging : KLoggable {
    override val logger: KLogger = logger()
}
```

suppose the following code is inside `catch (err: Exception){...}` what is the difference between
`logger.error { "Some error $err" }`
and
`logger.error(err) { "Some error $err" }`
?

Comment: These produce different logs, don't they? I'm pretty sure `logger.error(err)` will print the stack trace of the exception for most logging frameworks.

Comment: ok, thank you, now it's clear